# getline function memory leak when return value is -1

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>                              
int main(int argc, char** argv)                 
{                                               
    FILE *fp = NULL;                            
    char* line = NULL;                          
    ssize_t read = 0;                           
    ssize_t len = 0;                            
    fp = popen("lspci | grep aaaaaa", "r");     

    if((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) == -1){
        pclose(fp);                             
        return -1;                              
    }                                           

    pclose(fp);                                 
}
```

This is the test program.

I wrote the function test code here. I want to know when the function getline return -1 whether I need free the buffer. I test it in my environment. I found that when the getline function return -1, there are memory leak. The following is my debug step:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff754) at getline.c:8
8           FILE *fp = NULL;
(gdb) n
9           char* line = NULL;
(gdb)
10          ssize_t read = 0;
(gdb)
11          ssize_t len = 0;
(gdb)
12          fp = popen("lspci | grep aaaaaa", "r");
(gdb)
14          if((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) == -1){
(gdb) i locals
fp = 0x804b008
line = 0x0
read = 0
len = 0
(gdb) n
15              pclose(fp);
(gdb) i locals
fp = 0x804b008
line = 0x804b0b8 ""
read = -1
len = 120
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: What about the man-page of `getline` is unclear?

Comment: Hint: there is no `free()` call on the pointer with allocated memory.

Comment: @ John Bollinger. It is not a question. It just a statement about getline function. I want to let us know there is some potential hazard of this function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first issue of getline function. Another issue is here. I want to know whether getline function use realloc function, and free the buffer when the buffer is not enough. The following is another test code. I get the points that getline function initialize malloc memory with 128 bytes. but it doesn't use realloc function to alloc buffer when the buffer is not enough.

The following test code alloc 3 buffers. getline function buffer is in the middle. The initialized getline buffer is 128 bytes. Then I call the getline function again to get the buffers more than 128 bytes. I set a break point in free function,but it is not called.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)                 
{

    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *buffer1 = NULL;
    char *buffer2 = NULL;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters;


    buffer1 = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if( buffer1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("buffer1 = 0x%p\n", buffer1);
    printf("Type something: ");
    characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);

    printf(" get line buffer  = 0x%p\n", buffer);
    buffer2 = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if( buffer2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(buffer2, 21,bufsize);

    printf("buffer2 = 0x%p\n", buffer2);
    printf("buffer2 content = %s\n", buffer2);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
    printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);
    printf("The address is  = 0x%p\n", buffer);

    characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
    printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);
    printf("The address is change = 0x%p\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return(0);
}
```

Debug process:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff754) at getline.c:22
22          char *buffer = NULL;
(gdb) n
23          char *buffer1 = NULL;
(gdb)
24          char *buffer2 = NULL;
(gdb)
25          size_t bufsize = 32;
(gdb)
29          buffer1 = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
(gdb)
30          if( buffer1 == NULL)
(gdb)
36          printf("buffer1 = 0x%p\n", buffer1);
(gdb)
buffer1 = 0x0x804b008
38          printf("Type something: ");
(gdb)
39          characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
(gdb)
Type something: aaaaaa
41          printf(" get line buffer  = 0x%p\n", buffer);
(gdb)
 get line buffer  = 0x0x804b030
42          buffer2 = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
(gdb) n
43          if( buffer2 == NULL)
(gdb) n
48          memset(buffer2, 21,bufsize);
(gdb) n
50          printf("buffer2 = 0x%p\n", buffer2);
(gdb) n
buffer2 = 0x0x804b0b0
52          printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
(gdb) p  0xb0 -0x30
$1 = 128
(gdb) b free
Breakpoint 2 at 0xb7e8cc60: free. (2 locations)
(gdb) n
7 characters were read.
53          printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);
(gdb) n
You typed: 'aaaaaa
'
54          printf("The address is  = 0x%p\n", buffer);
(gdb) n
The address is  = 0x0x804b030
56          characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
(gdb)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
57          printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
(gdb) n
190 characters were read.
58          printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);
(gdb)
You typed: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
'
59          printf("The address is change = 0x%p\n", buffer);
(gdb)
The address is change = 0x0x804b130
60          free(buffer);
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x08048566 in main at getline.c:22
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
2       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>
2.1                         y     0xb7e8cc60 in __GI___libc_free at malloc.c:2912
2.2                         y     0xb7ff3730 in free at dl-minimal.c:119
```

Comment: It is so interesting for the function getline. It means that if I call the getline function unsuccessful. I need wipe the bottom again.